# Base table or view not found in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a model

> Education.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Education extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = FALSE;
    public function Member(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
    }
}
```

In database i have a table named ***educations***
In controller when I'm trying to access the data of the educations table through ***App\Education*** model I'm getting this error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table
>   or view not found: 1146 Table 'dsse.education' doesn't exist (SQL:
>   select * from `education`)

Why laravel is searching for ***education*** table in the database where it should search for ***educations*** table. What is the problem?

here is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Member as Member;
use App\Education as Education;

class memberController extends Controller
{
    public function addMember(){
        $education = Education::all();
        var_dump($education);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code from your controller?

Comment: I have added the controller in the question. Please check

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your model. You may set any custom table name as follow

```
protected $table = 'educations';
```

Comment: Yes that solve the problem. But why i have to mention the table name. By convention laravel should search for the educations table

Comment: Check your migration file first that how you create the table. May b you misspelled the table name like Schema::create('education', function (Blueprint $table) {} :) . Please check.

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem before,**

and yes it is a solution to add

```
protected $table = 'educations';
```

but the problem is because laravel uses a class called

```
Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer
```

inside

```
Illuminate\Support\Str
```

and this class is not just adding "s" at the end of words or ies...
it is real pluralizer and education is an uncountable word, so is information...
so **you need to add $table to your model**.